# Creating a ad hoc provisional profile without generating yet another public/private keypair

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

When creating ad hoc provisional profile, it asks for Certificate Signing Request.

It seems it would yet create a new set of public/private key pair? Can I use an existing one?

Below is the instruction given. The step I have in question is "create a name for your private key". I already have two key pairs I wish to use existing ones.

> To manually generate a Certificate, you need a Certificate Signing
>   Request (CSR) file from your Mac. To create a CSR file, follow the
>   instructions below to create one using Keychain Access. Create a CSR
>   file.
>
> In the Applications folder on your Mac, open the Utilities folder and
>   launch Keychain Access.
>
> Within the Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access >
>   Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate
>   Authority.
>
> ```
> In the Certificate Information window, enter the following information:
>     In the User Email Address field, enter your email address.
>     In the Common Name field, create a name for your private key (e.g., John Doe Dev Key).
>     The CA Email Address field should be left empty.
>     In the "Request is" group, select the "Saved to disk" option.
> Click Continue within Keychain Access to complete the CSR generating process.
> ```

Comment: It depends on what certificate you already had. I beleive you might have created development certificate previously. You need separate one for distribution profile. Once you have one for each you can use the same for all other profiles. .

Comment: I have two already. One for development, one for the app store. But I have not previously used ad hoc distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create Separate Certificate Signing Request (CSR) each time. You can use the same CSR as many time as you can. No problem on using same CSR each time. i use same CSR for creating certificates.

But you have to create at least one time

[image: keyychain CSR]

Comment: But you have to create CSR at least once. by going to

Comment: With that image aren't you doing the requesting? I've request it before for development profile and app store profile. But I've never done one for ad hoc.

Comment: Distribution certificate is used for ad hoc profile

Comment: Exactly what steps do I do to use **existing** public / private key pair and obtain a new certificate? I just don't know where to go about it. It looks like requesting a CSR would create yet another set of keys.

Comment: Oh you could upload an existing one. I've just see that option.

Comment: Yes we can upload the existing CSR which we created and uploaded before